# unable to use class key word in html link after php variable

Tags: php, html, css

I want to blink the link "view" but it says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vi_data.php on line 107

```
echo "<td width='150'> <a href='didata.php?id=".$diReturn- 
>diID.class="blinking""'><span> View </span> </a> </td> ";
```

Comment: You are missing a few different quotes - the double quote to start the literal text again and the close single quote from the href attribute - `$diReturn- 
>diID."' class`.  You also have problems with the quotes round the `blinking` value of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using concatenation in wrong way, do like below:

```
echo "<td width='150'> <a href='didata.php?id=". $diReturn->diID ."' class='blinking'><span> View </span> </a> </td> ";
```

Sample output (just for understanding purpose):- https://3v4l.org/MsjTk